# Customize a file in wp-includes will be lost when Wordpress is updated?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to ask if my modification in wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-rss.php will be lost when Wordpress is updated?
I am trying to remove the RSS icon, it works now but I wonder if it is overrided with Wordpress Update.
Thank you,

J Dang

Comment: I would always assume modifications to core components will be overwritten during an update.

Answer (score 0):

Never make any modification on core files, they will be erase with any WordPress update.

Filters and actions are here to change behaviour without editing core.

In your case, I think it's better to 'extend' the class wp-widget-rss.

You could find [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API), the way to extend the widget class, I think the same method can be use for the one you want to modify.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will try to modify it through API.